# List sorting prioritizing particular value

Tags: c#, sorting

I'd like to sort this list of strings giving priority to a certain string.  Beyond that, the ordinary string sorting will be fine.

In this example, "why am I so dumb?", which is the most obvious thing we can get out of this question, is intended to be sorted at the top of the list.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>() 
    { "foo", "bar", "why am I so dumb?", "tgif" };

    stringList.Sort(StringListSorter);

    stringList.ForEach(x => Console.Out.WriteLine(x));
}

static int StringListSorter(string s1, string s2)
{
    int retVal = 0;

    if (s1 == "why am I so dumb?")
    {
        retVal = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = s1.CompareTo(s2);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

In this example, the string desired to be at the top is somewhere in the middle of the list.

Comment: What if `s2` is the `"why am I so dumb?"` string?

Comment: As an aside, if you would use LINQ it would be more readable: `stringList=stringList.OrderByDescending(s=> s=="why am I so dumb?").ToList()`. This would keep the other strings' order unchanged, add `ThenBy(s=> s)` if you also want to order the rest.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the comment; I do agree that your approach is more elegant for my question.  In my actual situation, I'm afraid the logic for sorting my list may change over time and become a little more complex, which is why I'm leaning a little more towards the method and using List<T>.Sort(Comparer<T>)

Comment: @IAmJaeger: You can also use methods in LINQ queries and `OrderBy` uses a _stable_ sort as opposed to `List.Sort` which means that if two elements are equal the original order is preserved. However, the main argument for `List.Sort` is that it can be more efficient since it does not need to create a new list but orders the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison routine is incomplete.  You have accounted for the case where `s1 == "why am I so dumb?"`, but not the cases where `s2 == "why am I so dumb?"` or where *both* are `"why am I so dumb?"`.  Adding those cases should fix the problem (plus you can simplify it by `return`ing from the cases):

```
static int StringListSorter(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == s2)
        return 0;
    if (s1 == "why am I so dumb?")
        return -1;
    if (s2 == "why am I so dumb?")
        return 1;
    return s1.CompareTo(s2);
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something dumb.  Thank you!  Have a great weekend!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't undestand the question :-)
But, may be:

> stringList.Sort((s, s1) => s == "why am I so dumb?" ? -1 : s.CompareTo(s1));

or

> stringList.Sort((s, s1) => s == "why am I so dumb?" ? -1 : (s1 == "why am I so dumb?" ? 1 : s.CompareTo(s1)));

Comment: I believe the latter of these would do the trick whereas the former would have the problem in my initial example.