# Best way to prioritize certain Strings while sorting a Map

Tags: java, string, sorting, compare, treemap

I'd like to sort a map with strings, so that certain strings are prioritized and the rest is ordered as usual.

Like this:

```
"Dan",   "value"  //priority 1
"Eric",  "value"  //priority 2
"Ann",   "value"  //priority 3
"Bella", "value"  //no priority
"Chris", "value"  //no priority
```

Just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066978/) question.

I'm using a TreeMap and my current compare method looks like this:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (o1.equals(o2)) return 0;
    if (o1.equals("Dan")) return -1;
    if (o2.equals("Dan")) return 1;
    if (o1.equals("Eric")) return -1;
    if (o2.equals("Eric")) return 1;
    if (o1.equals("Ann")) return -1;
    if (o2.equals("Ann")) return 1;
    else return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

As you can see, this gets quite cumbersome with more prioritized Strings.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

Solution (thanks to amit for the idea):
Use a 2nd map to store the priorities:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> prio = new TreeMap<>();
prio.put("Dan", 1);
prio.put("Eric", 2);
prio.put("Ann", 3);

comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (prio.containsKey(o1)) {
            if (prio.containsKey(o2)) {
                return prio.get(o1).compareTo(prio.get(o2));
            } else return -1;
        } else if (prio.containsKey(o2)) {
            return 1;
        } else return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
```

Comment: prioritized in which way? by enumeration? by other criteria?

Comment: I want to give certain strings a hard coded priority.
(I edited the question accordingly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a 2nd map:

`Map<String,Integer> prio` where the value is the priority of each string.

In your comparator - first compare according to `prio.get(o1).compareTo(prio.get(o2))`<sup>1</sup>, and only if the result is 0, fall back to regular String's `compareTo()`.

It is important that `prio` does not change after your `map` is created, otherwise your map will be a complete chaos without an ability to find and insert elements properly.

---

(1) Make sure both elements exist first in `prio`, and if one does not - resolve.

Comment: I added my implementation of your idea to the question. It seems to do the work. And even if it might be a bit much for only 3 prioritized strings, it at least looks not as stupid as my queue of ifs :P - thank you